# What's the best way to take out enemy jets using the default jet equipment?

Tags: battlefield-3

I find jet warfare hard in BF3.

I have not unlocked any abilities with the jet and would like to know what's the best way to spot and kill enemy jets with the standard gun. I find it hard to spot and to aim at the enemy jet when flying.

Any ideas or tricks would be helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best weapon period for taking out enemy jets is the default machine gun.

Heat-Seekers can be evaded or they can use flares to get rid of them. The only thing that an enemy can do to avoid being shot by a machine gun is be a better pilot than you, and even then, if you get the drop on them, it's pretty hard to avoid being killed.

The machine gun also kills the most quickly of any of the jets weapons. The only downside to it is that you have to learn how far to lead the enemy jet to hit them. This comes from practice, and soon you'll be able to take down an enemy jet no problem.

In regards to spotting and keeping track of the enemy, the first thing you want to do is look at the enemy jet and press <kbd>Q</kbd>. Then once you've engaged the enemy, stay in cockpit view whenever you can to help you aim, but the moment that the enemy moves out of your view, switch to chase camera (<kbd>C</kbd>) and attempt to keep them in your sights. Switch back and forth between cockpit cam and chase cam whenever you get a chance to fire at them.

If you follow these tips pretty soon you'll be taking out enemy jets like a pro.

Comment: Do you use the mouse or arrow keys or a gamepad to fly the jet? (what is your personal preference?)

Comment: @StevenLu I use a gamepad, but when I'm not using my gamepad, I use the keyboard only (wasd + arrow keys).

Answer (score 1):

I find that the machine gun is the most reliable and as you can do varying levels of damage depending on where you hit the aircraft you may find a clip on the wing does enough to disable the vehicle.